# How can I use the platform specific styling on the Android platform?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an application with a simple layout that contains a few buttons. When running the application on "plain" android (a G1 with 1.6) the buttons look like they do elsewhere on the phone (grey gradients). They also look more or less the same on Sony Ericsson X10 Mini Pro (with 2.1), but the buttons in other applications on the X10 Mini (eg dialer, pin code input) looks very different (transparent).

Is it possible to somehow make sure that the buttons and other form input elements use the platform (for lack of a better word) styling across different Android devices?

Comment: No this is not possible. Those apps look different because they're probably using custom buttons. It might be possible to use the same buttons the other apps are using, but there's no portable way to use the same images that another app on the phone uses.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering, I was afraid that was the case.. I'll just stick with the default styling then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Falmarri already commented, this is not possible. Falmarri, why don't post an answer to this? ;)
Some time ago I was trying to get the default colors of the buttons of the currently used theme (they also depend on the model and the operator and so on) but in Android this is not possible. In my opinion, this is a lack of flexibility that harms us programmers because applications we build do not look well-integrated into the environment.

Comment: I agree, I was also a bit stumped to learn that this was the case. I also noticed that that it's not very well integrated by default (on G1) - the Dialer, Calculator and e.g. contact edit form all look very different.